# Gnokii working in Linux command line but not in PHP system command

Tags: php, mobile-phones

Gnokii working in Linux command line in RHEL5 but not through PHP system command. What to check?

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) is (correctly) preventing httpd from executing gnokii. httpd runs as `httpd_t`, gnokii is labelled as `bin_t`, and there's no domain transition from one to the next. Solutions include disabling SELinux completely (not recommended), allowing httpd_t to freely execute bin_t (also not recommended), and giving gnokii a new file context and creating a domain transition rule for it.

Running `man httpd_selinux` gives a bit more information, but in order to create a new transition rule you'll need to see the various resources linked to on the SELinux website.